# File types supported in iOS 15 WebShare

Tags: javascript, ios, chromium, web-share

I've started exploring the WebShare API [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#specifications). I found that Chromium has a limitation to what file types can be shared. I need to be able to share different file types like .xlsx and .docx for example. I'm unable to find any information on what types iOS supports.

My thought is that I let iOS users use the share feature if there is support for my needs and chromium based browsersm I will find some work around for.

Question is. Does anyone have knowledge about the file types available for sharing in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a list of allow-listed file types that Safari supports, but [according to the spec](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#:%7E:text=if%20the%20user%20agent%20believes%20sharing%20any%20of%20the%20files%20in%20files%20would%20result%20in%20a%20potentially%20hostile%20share%2C%20return%20false.) you can run the [`canShare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/canShare) method before the sharing attempt since it will throw…

> [i]f the user agent believes sharing any of the files in `files` would result in a potentially hostile share[.]